# How to structure a Visual Studio project code base to be deployed to a number of websites with different config transformations?

Tags: visual-studio, umbraco, go-cd

An Umbraco Visual Studio solution with a single project acting as the core code base that is to be deployed to a number of websites. Each website will have it's own config file transformations, CSS, JS and View overrides. When the core code base is updated, this will need to be deployed to all of the websites.

I've toyed with the idea of separate repositories per website installing the core code base via a private NuGet package, but thought that might be quite time consuming as the number of websites grow, having to update each individual repository.

The ideally scenario in my head would be for the build server/client, GoCD, to somehow merge the core code base with each individual website and deploy accordingly.

Looking for any suggestions on how to approach this.

Comment: Do the websites need to be on separate servers, or can you do this as a multi-site solution within a single Umbraco instance? It could be as easy as setting multiple home nodes and structuring your Umbraco project around the separate sites, or as you've said, having a single core repository and separate repositories for the rest of the code.

Comment: We have gone down the route of separate Umbraco instances per website. Some of those instances will have multi-sites in them for the language variations.

Comment: In that case, I would try to abstract as much away as you can and go down the private NuGet route you've already suggested. I've done this on a few projects, and as long as the "master" library is strong enough it was easy enough to build a standard structure with minimal parts. On the config transformation front, I've always found Octopus Deploy's handling of config transforms to be useful for multi-server/environment deploys.

Comment: I've seen some ideas around having each project setup as their own repository and the solution as another repository. Each project is then added in as a submodule to the solution. Need to try a proof of concept.

Comment: It depends on the requirements you have. We had a situation where both sites (targeted at different countries) had exact same template (css/html) so we created two root nodes within Umbraco. In another case the sites had same structure but different css and deployed seperately, so we put the css files under "content/{CountryCode} folders and created different style bundles. The applicable style bundle was selected based on CountryCode specified in web.config file.